# How many Sylow p-subgroups are in this group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> By direct computation, find the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups and the number of Sylow $5$-subgroups of the symmetric group $S_5$.
>
> Solution: In $S_5$ there are $20$ three cycles which split up into $10$ subgroups of order $3$. This number is congruent to $1 \mod 3$ and is a divisor of ($5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$).
>
> There are $24$ five cycles which split up into $6$ subgroups of order $5$. This number is congruent to $1 \mod 5$ and is a divisor of ($5 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$).

My question is where did the numbers $10$ subgroups and $6$ subgroups come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (cyclic) group of order 3 is always of the form 
$$\{e,a,a^{-1}\} $$
where $e$ is the identity, and $a$ and $a^{-1}$ have order 3. Thus the number $10$ is the result of the calculation $$\frac{20}{3-1}=\frac{20}{2}$$
(the identity element is not of order 3). Similarly

$$6=\frac{24}{5-1}. $$

Comment: To add a bit, although probably unnecessary: in $S_5$, any $n$-cycle is conjugate to any other $n$-cycle. Therefore the 2 non-trivial elements in a $3$-Sylow subgroup are in the same conjugacy class, and likewise for the 4 non-trivial elements in a $5$-subgroup. Hence the calculation above holds. In $A_5$, in contrast, for instance, there are two $5$-cycle conjugacy classes, and a $5$-Sylow subgroup $<b>$ splits into $A_5$-conjugacy classes $b, b^{-1}$, and $b^2,b^{-2}$.